# Returning only one boolean statement if two matrices identical

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

Suppose there is a matrix `A` and a matrix `B`. Is there a logical statement that can return only one value, either `True` or `False` based on whether all elements of `A` are identical to all elements in `B`?

For example `A = array([[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0]])` and `B = array([[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0]])`, `A == B` returns `True` and `False` per element of every row and every column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html).

Also, you can apply `.all()` to the equality-bool-array you got by comparing `A==B`, like this:

```
(A==B).all()
```

The latter is slightly less efficient than the former (creates a temporary bool array), but just as common.

If comparing floats, where you typically want the value to be close but not necessarily identical, use [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).